# How to merge two geometries or meshes using three.js r71?

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js

Here I bumped to the problem since I need to merge two geometries (or meshes) to one. Using the earlier versions of three.js there was a nice function:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(pendulum, ball);
```

However, it is not on the new version anymore.

I tried to merge `pendulum` and `ball` with the following code:

`ball` is a mesh.

```
var ballGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(24,35,35);
var ballMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xF7FE2E}); 
var ball = new THREE.Mesh(ballGeo, ballMat); 
ball.position.set(0,0,0);

var pendulum = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 20, 16);
ball.updateMatrix();
pendulum.merge(ball.geometry, ball.matrix);
scene.add(pendulum);
```

After all, I got the following error:

```
THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. THREE.CylinderGeometry {uuid: "688B0EB1-70F7-4C51-86DB-5B1B90A8A24C", name: "", type: "CylinderGeometry", vertices: Array[1332], colors: Array[0]…}THREE.error @ three_r71.js:35THREE.Object3D.add @ three_r71.js:7770(anonymous function) @ pendulum.js:20
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally, I found a possible solution. I am posting since it could be useful for somebody else while I wasted a lot of hours. The tricky thing is about manipulating the concept of meshes and geometries:

```
var ballGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,35,35);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xF7FE2E}); 
var ball = new THREE.Mesh(ballGeo, material);

var pendulumGeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 1, 50, 16);
ball.updateMatrix();
pendulumGeo.merge(ball.geometry, ball.matrix);

var pendulum = new THREE.Mesh(pendulumGeo, material);
scene.add(pendulum);
```

Comment: _"Needless were none of the deeds of Tyler Crompton in life"_ - _Lady Galadriel_

Thanks for this

Comment: This is a very useful solution, which even allows rotation of mesh2 around mesh1 if mesh1.position.set(xx, 0, 0); If it is set to (0, 0, 0) it is centered inside or surrounding mesh1 dependant of the size.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Used it for a method to merge new Meshes / geometries into existing ones.


`function AddToGeometry(mainObject, objectToAdd) {
objectToAdd.updateMatrix();
mainObject.geometry.merge(objectToAdd.geometry, objectToAdd.matrix);
return mainObject;
    }`

Comment: Why do we need Meshes? As I understood the documentation, you can merge geometries without creating meshes. Am I wrong? Also, even if you do need meshes, wouldn't it be better to dispose the first two not used anymore after merging?

Answer (score 44):

To explain Darius' answer more clearly (as I struggled with it, while trying to update a version of Mr Doob's procedural city to work with the Face3 boxes):

Essentially you are merging all of your Meshes into a single Geometry. So, if you, for instance, want to merge a box and sphere:

```
var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.65, 32, 32);
```

...into a single geometry:

```
var singleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
```

...you would create a Mesh for each geometry:

```
var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(box);
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere);
```

...then call the merge method of the single geometry for each, passing the geometry and matrix of each into the method:

```
boxMesh.updateMatrix(); // as needed
singleGeometry.merge(boxMesh.geometry, boxMesh.matrix);

sphereMesh.updateMatrix(); // as needed
singleGeometry.merge(sphereMesh.geometry, sphereMesh.matrix);
```

Once merged, create a mesh from the single geometry and add to the scene:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

A working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r77/three.js"></script>
<!-- OrbitControls.js is not versioned and may stop working with r77 -->
<script src='http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>

<body style='margin: 0px; background-color: #bbbbbb; overflow: hidden;'>
  <script>
    // init renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // init scene and camera
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 3000);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera)
    
    // our code
    var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.65, 32, 32);

    var singleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(box);
    var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere);

    boxMesh.updateMatrix(); // as needed
    singleGeometry.merge(boxMesh.geometry, boxMesh.matrix);

    sphereMesh.updateMatrix(); // as needed
    singleGeometry.merge(sphereMesh.geometry, sphereMesh.matrix);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // a light
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xfffff0, 0x101020, 1.25);
    light.position.set(0.75, 1, 0.25);
    scene.add(light);
 
    // render
    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     renderer.render(scene, camera);  
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

At least, that's how I am interpreting things; apologies to anyone if I have something wrong, as I am no where close to being a three.js expert (currently learning). I just had the "bad luck" to try my hand at customizing Mr. Doob's procedural city code, when the latest version breaks things (the merge stuff being one of them, the fact that three.js no longer uses quads for cube -ahem- box geometry the other - which has led to all kinds of fun getting the shading and such to work properly again).

Comment: thanks for this.   updating some code i just ported from having 500,000 warnings was looking quite daunting.  I am not very happy about the way this was handled, finding the answer was way too difficult for something I have no control over.

Answer (score 6):

The error message is right. CylinderGeometry is not an Object3D. Mesh is. A Mesh is constructed from a Geometry and a Material. A Mesh can be added to the scene, while a Geometry cannot.

In the newest versions of three.js, Geometry has two merge methods: *merge* and *mergeMesh*.

- *merge* takes a mandatory argument *geometry*, and two optional arguments *matrix* and *materialIndexOffset*.
- geom.*mergeMesh*(mesh) is basically a shorthand for geom.*merge*(mesh.*geometry*, mesh.*matrix*), as used in other answers. ('geom' and 'mesh' being arbitrary names for a Geometry and a Mesh, respectively.) The Material of the Mesh is ignored.

Comment: mergeMesh for the win. It's much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

This is my ultimate compact version in four (or five) lines (as long as material is defined somewhere else) making use of mergeMesh:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
geom.mergeMesh(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,20,2)));
geom.mergeMesh(new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,5,5)));
geom.mergeVertices(); // optional
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geom, material));
```

Edit: added optional extra line to remove duplicate vertices, which should help performance.

Edit 2: I'm using the newest version, 94.

Comment: Please, give us the number of the current version you are using?

Comment: That looks good. Does it also work for ```BufferGeometry``` that uses ```VertexColor```?

Comment: are `.Geometry()` is now `BufferGeometry` ? ver 130

Comment: mergeMesh and mergeVertices are not found while 'merge'ing doesn't error it doesn't work version 131

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries

Answer (score 0):

The answers and code that I've seen posted here do not work because the second argument of the merge method is an integer, not a matrix. As far as I can tell, the merge method is not really functioning in a useful way. Therefore, I used the following approach to make a simple rocket with a nose cone.

```
import * as BufferGeometryUtils from '../three.js/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js'

lengthSegments = 2
radius = 5
radialSegments = 32
const bodyLength = dParamWithUnits['launchVehicleBodyLength'].value
const noseConeLength = dParamWithUnits['launchVehicleNoseConeLength'].value

// Create the vehicle's body
const launchVehicleBodyGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(radius, radius, bodyLength, radialSegments, lengthSegments, false)
launchVehicleBodyGeometry.name = "body"
// Create the nose cone
const launchVehicleNoseConeGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, radius,  noseConeLength, radialSegments, lengthSegments, false)
launchVehicleNoseConeGeometry.name = "noseCone"
launchVehicleNoseConeGeometry.translate(0, (bodyLength+noseConeLength)/2, 0)
// Merge the nosecone into the body
const launchVehicleGeometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries([launchVehicleBodyGeometry, launchVehicleNoseConeGeometry])
// Rotate the vehicle to horizontal
launchVehicleGeometry.rotateX(-Math.PI/2)
const launchVehicleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x7f3f00})
const launchVehicleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(launchVehicleGeometry, launchVehicleMaterial)
```